# Can the B-value for NTC be used to extrapolate beyond the B range?

Tags: thermistor

Most NTC thermistors have operating range way beyond the single B value specified in the datasheet. For example [NTCALUG01A473HA](https://www.vishay.com/docs/29092/ntcalug01a.pdf) has operating range -40..150C but only B25/85 specified.

Can I use basic R = R25 * exp(B(1/t - 1/298.15)) formula to estimate resistance at say 100..127C range?

The reason I am asking is that some devices have long tables that seem to indicate that B value varies rather significantly in different regions of the operating range. Unfortunately for several reasons I have to choose the part by the mechanical construction, so finding the one with suitable B-value range is problematic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd be better off to use the extended Steinhart-Hart equations.

You can find the coefficients [here](https://www.vishay.com/en/thermistors/ntc-rt-calculator/)

A= -15.53215593

B= 5229.973

C= -160451.

D= -5414091.

Rt = \$R_{25}(e^{(A + B/T + C/T^2 + D/T^3)}) \$

\$R_{25}\$ is the resistance at 25°C (47k in this case)

T is the absolute temperature of the sensor

Of course you can also use the calculator on the linked page or the above equations to calculate \$\beta\$ for any temperature range you desire within the -40°C to 150°C range, but it's more accurate to use the full equation.

From my recollection if you attempt to extrapolate using the beta for a narrower range the error will increase rapidly as you go beyond the original range. If you calculate a new beta for the new wider range the error will be higher than if you had a narrow range, but it will be much lower than if you extrapolated.

Comment: huh... that link was right in the datasheet. I need to pay more attention to that stuff... Thanks! I am planning on measuring the actual device once I have it, but I needed a ballpark to know if it fits at all.

Comment: One more thing, "If you calculate a new beta for the new wider range the error will be higher ". Is the reverse true? i.e. if I calculate beta for reduced range the error will be lower? I only need 100..127C to add overheat protection to power FET. Actually, I don't really need precision. I only want to shut down the driver around 127-140C and enable it again when radiator cools down to 100-110C

Comment: @Maple if yoy just want to turn off something and not seeking some gradual effect, you may be better off using a bimetal switch

Comment: Yes the reverse is also true. But if you only need the exact resistance at one or two temperatures (say to design a comparator with precise on and off switching points) you can just calculate those accurately with the calculator or equations and be done with it. The equations or tables are most useful if you want to display or control the temperature over a wide range.

Comment: There will be tolerances in the thermistor, and in  your circuitry so it doesn't hurt to get the nominal numbers bang-on since that's only a bit of virtuous personal effort vs. something like added component cost or (often worse) calibration, at least that's how I think of it.

Comment: It's like you are looking over my shoulder. Yes, I have a comparator (MCP6541) with hysteresis set by two resistors and output connected to enable input of the gate driver. It is to calculate those resistors and thermistor divider I asked this question. I am using 0.1% parts exactly to give the thermistor some leeway